# Document adminnotification_inbox can not be copied directly

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, data-migration-tool

while data migrating from magento 1.9.2.3 to Magento 2.3.4 with data migration tool, the error as shown in the screenshot is displayed. Could anyone please enlighten me on why it occurs and the fix for the it? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whether to migrate this document(adminnotification_inbox) is a choice which in most of the cases can be ignored as this table maintains the messages that Magento circulate time to time. Since one is migrating to M2, one will have to focus more on the notifications from Magento to keep the store up to date.